# How do I Reject all SMTP traffic except from a specified IP Block using DD-WRT?

Tags: iptables, smtp, router, port-forwarding

I am running DD-WRT v24-sp2 std firmware on a Linksys WRT54GL.

I have a port forward configured on port 25 to ip 10.10.10.1. What I want to do is allow this port forwarding, but only from WAN IP's in the range 64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255.

How can this be done?

Comment: What does the manual on the Linksys say?

Comment: @mdpc probably not much. The router is NOT running linksys firmware, so the manual would not make any mention about how to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The firmware on this router is DD-WRT and I am able to make iptables entries that work. The difficulty that I'm having is in setting the right entries.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to dig into the firewall guide for this.

[Firewall Guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firewall)

[Firewall Example using iptables](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/FirewallExample)

Something like this:

```
#iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -s remote.ip.address/netmask -d $WAN_IP --dport 25 -j DNAT --to $LAN_IP:25
#iptables -I NAT -p tcp -d $WAN_IP --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

and remove any port forwarding rules you have on the NAT page, so you don't cause issues.